# UK: what do I need to declare?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, household, switzerland

I have a question about declaration and tax in UK. I am British, a resident of UK, British passport, no duel citizenship.

A) If I have a property (holiday home) abroad within EU which I do not rent or receive any income from, would I need to declare this or pay anything to UK government? ***EDIT***This country **[the country the holiday home is in]** already has a non-residence tax which I pay (very annoying).

B) Swiss account with money, but no interest?

C) Swiss account either savings or investment which I get income from
etc...

If so, how would I go about declaring them? Keeping in mind this is a small amount of money we are discussing.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you file a self assessment at the end of a financial year. There is a foreign section in the form.

> When you need to fill in the foreign section:-

- were entitled to any foreign income, or income gains
- have, or could have, received (directly or indirectly) income, or a capital payment or benefit from a person abroad as a result of any transfer of assets
- want to claim relief for foreign tax paid

a) No income received you don't need to mention in your SA. But if you want to reclaim the non-residence tax you will need to fill up the foreign section part of the SA. I am not so clear about the appreciation in the price of the house will be classified as income gain or not, better get it clarified from an accountant.

b) Same as above

c) Need to mention on your SA and fill in the foreign section.

Legally speaking, small amount or large amount doesn't matter. As long as it is income it needs to go in your SA.

Comment: Thank you, it all makes sense, but in regards to point A, I updated my question because there is a possibility you misunderstood it first time sorry. I pay the non-residence tax to the country where my house is (outside of UK). Are you saying that I should declare in Self Assessment that I am paying a non-residence tax abroad? If I do this what will happen, I get a cheque in the mail? Sorry for question I am asking on behalf of someone else.

Comment: @k1308517 - The UK has a principal of no double-taxation. This means that if you have been taxed on something abroad, that amount is deducted from whatever tax you would have paid on it to HMRC, *limited to the amount of tax you would have paid on that particular item*. As HMRC doesn't tax you for the privilege of owning foreign property, there will be no tax relief on it.

Comment: @AndyT Oh okay, thought I was going to get my 80 euro back, along with the 60 I pay my accountant over there.